# How to write "asInstanceOfOption" in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to write an "asInstanceOfOption" method that would do what is intended by the following (bogus) code?

```
def asInstanceOfOption[T](o: Any): Option[T] =
   if (o.isInstanceOf[T]) Some(o.asInstanceOf[T]) else None
```

Comment: That is a very clever idiom, and oxbow's answer was very clever as well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**EDIT** *Below is my original answer but you can accomplish this now with*

```
def asInstanceOfOption[T: ClassTag](o: Any): Option[T] = 
  Some(o) collect { case m: T => m}
```

---

You could use manifests to get around the fact that the type `T` is *erased* at compile time:

```
scala> import scala.reflect._
import scala.reflect._

scala> def asInstanceOfOption[B](x : Any)(implicit m: Manifest[B]) : Option[B] = {
   | if (Manifest.singleType(x) <:< m)
   |   Some(x.asInstanceOf[B])
   | else
   |   None
   | }
asInstanceOfOption: [B](x: Any)(implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[B])Option[B]
```

Then this could be used:

```
scala> asInstanceOfOption[Int]("Hello")
res1: Option[Int] = None

scala> asInstanceOfOption[String]("World")
res2: Option[String] = Some(World)
```

You could even use *implicit conversions* to get this to be a method available on `Any`. I think I prefer the method name `matchInstance`:

```
implicit def any2optionable(x : Any) = new { //structural type
  def matchInstance[B](implicit m: Manifest[B]) : Option[B] = {
    if (Manifest.singleType(x) <:< m)
      Some(x.asInstanceOf[B])
    else
      None
  }   
}
```

Now you can write code like:

```
"Hello".matchInstance[String] == Some("Hello") //true
"World".matchInstance[Int] == None             //true
```

EDIT: updated code for 2.9.x, where one can't use `Any` but only `AnyRef`:

```
implicit def any2optionable(x : AnyRef) = new { //structural type
  def matchInstance[B](implicit m: Manifest[B]) : Option[B] = {
    if (Manifest.singleType(x) <:< m)
      Some(x.asInstanceOf[B])
    else
      None
  }   
}
```

Comment: Only one observation; the "structural type" uses reflection to invoke the `matchInstance` method. If performance is more critical you could use a standard conversion to a non-structural type

Comment: The `matchInstance` method is _not_ invoked using reflection, since that is _not_ a structural type but just an anonymous class.

Comment: It seems this now only works with AnyRef -- I've posted a question about Any: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873936/how-to-write-asinstanceofoptt-where-t-any

Comment: Kim Stebel: sorry, you're factually incorrect. Luckily, Scala 2.10 with the -feature option gives a warning about this.

Comment: To get the warning you must use the added method, as in `"".matchInstance[String]`.

Comment: @KimStebel: see my comment above (I had forgot how to tag you).
To clarify my comment: matchInstance is part of an anonymous class, but the return type of a method cannot mention anonymous classes, so its type is just `Object {def matchInstance[B](implicit m: Manifest[B]): Option[B]}`.
I also answered MattR's question; there I avoid the problem with reflective calls by having the implicit conversion produce a class `IfInstanceOfAble` with the desired method.

Comment: Can somebody clarify the final full solution?  The `Some(x) collect...` solution - it needs to be wrapped inside a def.  Does that def require a `ClassTag`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an elaboration on oxbow_lake's updated answer, further updated to require Scala 2.10:

```
// Implicit value class
implicit class Castable(val obj: AnyRef) extends AnyVal {
  def asInstanceOfOpt[T <: AnyRef : ClassTag] = {
    obj match {
      case t: T => Some(t)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

This can be used by doing:

```
"Hello".asInstanceOfOpt[String] == Some("Hello") // true
"foo".asInstanceOfOpt[List[_]] == None // true
```

However as mentioned in other answers this doesn't work for primitives because of boxing issues, nor does it handle generics because of erasure.  To disallow primitives, I restricted `obj` and `T` to extend `AnyRef`.  For a solution that handles primitives, refer to the answer for Matt R's followup question:

[How to write asInstanceOfOpt[T] where T <: Any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873936/how-to-write-asinstanceofoptt-where-t-any)

Or use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s Typeable, which handles primitives as well as many erasure cases:

[Type casting using type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288975/type-casting-using-type-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of the writing of oxbow_lakes's answer (late '09), I believe `scala.util.Try` was not available, however, now (i.e. as of 2.10) I think `scala.util.Try` is the preferred (or well at least nicer-looking) way of doing this:

```
scala> Try((3).asInstanceOf[String]).toOption
res0: Option[String] = None

scala> Try("hello".asInstanceOf[String]).toOption
res1: Option[String] = Some(hello)
```

This relies on exceptions, so probably not the preferred style for performance critical blocks of code.

Comment: Why its this preferable to oxbow_lake's `Some(x) collect { case m : MyType => m }`? Try will raise an exception and handle it, which seems a bit excessive...

Comment: @Paul: if you mean performance, then you might be right; I just think it's more readable and easier to type as well.

Comment: OK. Readability is always personal of course, but I think the collect is clear (says more directly what is intended)

Comment: @Paul: for me *"tentatively convert `x` to `SomeType`"* is more readable... because you're not collecting anything... `collect` is just a technical word in this case, and so is `Some`... in my example, only `toOption` is technical.