# How to write asInstanceOfOpt[T] where T <: Any

Tags: scala

There's a handy implementation of `asInstanceOfOpt`, a safe version of `asInstanceOf`, given in the answer to [How to write "asInstanceOfOption" in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803036/how-to-write-asinstanceofoption-in-scala). It appears that, Scala 2.9.1, this solution now only works with AnyRef:

```
class WithAsInstanceOfOpt(obj: AnyRef) {
  def asInstanceOfOpt[B](implicit m: Manifest[B]): Option[B] =
    if (Manifest.singleType(obj) <:< m)
      Some(obj.asInstanceOf[B])
    else
      None
}
```

Can this be rewritten to support Any?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the Scala API the function `singleType` takes a parameter of type AnyRef. I don't really know the background for this decision, but it seems you need to work around it. Instead of using the method `singleType` I'd suggest using the `classType` method which basically can make a manifest for any class. It'll take a bit more code, but it could look something like this:

```
class WithAsInstanceOfOpt(obj : Any) {
  def asInstanceOfOpt[B : Manifest] : Option[B] =   // [B : Manifest] is shorthand for [B](implicit m : Manifest[B])
    if (Manifest.classType(manifest, obj.getClass) <:< manifest)
      Some(obj.asInstanceOf[B])
    else None
}
```

Comment: The above code does not work because of boxing. `1.asInstanceOfOpt[Int]` returns `None`, while `1.asInstanceOfOpt[java.lang.Integer]` returns `Some(1)` with type `Option[Integer]`. One needs to map the types manually (I'm gonna post a solution).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s Typeable from Miles Sabin:

[Type casting using type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288975/type-casting-using-type-parameter)

It handles primitives and boxing:

```
scala> import shapeless._; import syntax.typeable._
import shapeless._
import syntax.typeable._

scala> 1.cast[Int]
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> 1.cast[String]
res2: Option[String] = None

scala> "hello".cast[String]
res4: Option[String] = Some(hello)

scala> "foo".cast[Int]
res5: Option[Int] = None
```

You can see the source here to see how it's written:

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeable.scala

Answer (score 0):

Here's working code for 2.9.x. It will give deprecation warnings for 2.10.x, but using `ClassTag` instead of `Manifest` and `runtimeClass` instead of `erasure` will fix them.

```
//Precondition: classS must have been produced through primitiveToBoxed, because v will be boxed.
def ifInstanceOfBody[T, S](v: T, classS: Class[_]): Option[S] = {
  if (v == null || !classS.isInstance(v))
    None
  else
    Some(v.asInstanceOf[S])
}
object ClassUtil {
  import java.{lang => jl}

  private val primitiveToBoxedMap = Map[Class[_], Class[_]](
    classOf[Byte] -> classOf[jl.Byte],
    classOf[Short] -> classOf[jl.Short],
    classOf[Char] -> classOf[jl.Character],
    classOf[Int] -> classOf[jl.Integer],
    classOf[Long] -> classOf[jl.Long],
    classOf[Float] -> classOf[jl.Float],
    classOf[Double] -> classOf[jl.Double],
    classOf[Boolean] -> classOf[jl.Boolean],
    classOf[Unit] -> classOf[jl.Void]
  )
  def primitiveToBoxed(classS: Class[_]) =
    primitiveToBoxedMap.getOrElse(classS, classS)
}
class IfInstanceOfAble[T](v: T) {
  def asInstanceOfOpt[S](implicit cS: Manifest[S]): Option[S] =
    ifInstanceOfBody[T, S](v, ClassUtil.primitiveToBoxed(cS.erasure))
}
implicit def pimpInstanceOf[T](t: T) = new IfInstanceOfAble(t)
```

Testing results:

```
scala> 1.asInstanceOfOpt[Int]
res9: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> "".asInstanceOfOpt[String]
res10: Option[String] = Some()

scala> "foo".asInstanceOfOpt[String]
res11: Option[String] = Some(foo)

scala> 1.asInstanceOfOpt[String]
res12: Option[String] = None

scala> "".asInstanceOfOpt[Int]
res13: Option[Int] = None
```

The code is slightly more verbose than needed here, mostly because I took it from an existing codebase of mine where I reuse ifInstanceOfBody elsewhere. Inlining into `asInstanceOfOpt` would fix that and shorten the code somewhat, but most of it is for `primitiveToBoxedMap`, and trust me that I could not find something like that available in the Scala standard library.