# Scala Any => native format

Tags: scala, polymorphism, type-erasure, classtag

I have a map of type `Map[_, Any]`, and I want to extract the values in their native format (without resorting to `.asInstanceOf[_]`).

Something like this...

```
val m: Map[String, Any] = Map("i" -> 1, "s" -> "test")

val i: Option[Int] = m.get("i")
val s: Option[String] = m.get("s")
```

Obviously that fails.

I don't like this approach, but I was thinking I could do something like this...  but even this still comes out as `Any` instead of `Int` or `String`.

```
trait MyType[A] {
  def value: A
}

implicit class MyInt(i: Int) extends MyType[Int] { def value: Int = i }
implicit class MyString(s: String) extends MyType[String] { def value: String = s }

val m: Map[String, MyType[_]] = Map("i" -> 1, "s" -> "test")

val i: Option[Int] = m.get("i").map(_.value)
val s: Option[String] = m.get("s").map(_.value)
```

Then I thought maybe some wrapper around the `Map`...

```
case class MyMap(m: Map[String, Any]) {
  def get[A](k: String)(implicit ev: Option[Any] => Option[A]): Option[A] = m.get(k)
}
```

But that STILL comes out as `Any`.  I just can't figure out how to convert Any => native.

So my questions are...

1. Why does this fail?
2. What are better way(s) to get the values out in their native format?  Simplest and/or no external dependencies would be ideal...  but I'm honestly open to anything (though caveat I'm still on scala 2.11 for now).

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't it fail? Compiler has no way of knowing that a value associated with some random string would turn out to be `Int` or `String`.

Comment: The moment you have an **Any** that is all you will know about it. Your approach doesn't even make sense the **Map** is probably a runtime value, how would the compiler travel in time to infer which type the value will have in all the endless possibilities? - A better question would be, what is the problem you are trying to solve? This looks like a **Json**.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22852109/2707792

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot guess the runtime type for the reasons that have already been explained in the comments - this information is not there, once it's `Any`, all type information is lost, there is nothing you can do about it.

So, you'll have to provide the expected type yourself. How about an `.as[T]` helper method?

```
// This code is specifically for 2.11, please don't use it for more recent versions,
// see link below.

val m: Map[String, Any] = Map("i" -> 1, "s" -> "test")

import scala.reflect.{ ClassTag, classTag }

implicit class As(a: Any) {
  def as[T](implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): Option[T] = ct.unapply(a)
}

println(m("i").as[Int].map(_ + 41).get)
println(m("s").as[String].map("This is a " + _).get)
```

This will print

```
42
This is a test
```

Brief explanation:

- The `As` wrapper "pimps" all the objects, and attaches an `.as` method to everything.
- The `unapply` does the checking, the casting, and the wrapping in an `Option`.

It will not work for generic types like `List[Int]` vs. `List[String]` etc, because this information is simply not available at runtime.

**EDIT**: Thanks @MarioGalic for greatly simplifying the solution.