# Type casting using type parameter

Tags: scala, reflection, shapeless

Given is a Java method that returns `java.lang.Object`s for a given string. I'd like to wrap this method in a Scala method that converts the returned instances to some type `T`. If the conversion fails, the method should return `None`. I am looking for something similar to this:

```
def convert[T](key: String): Option[T] = {
  val obj = someJavaMethod(key)
  // return Some(obj) if obj is of type T, otherwise None
}

convert[Int]("keyToSomeInt") // yields Some(1)
convert[String]("keyToSomeInt") // yields None
```

(How) Can this be achieved using Scala's reflection API? I am well aware that the signature of `convert` might have to be altered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's what a `ClassTag` is for:

```
import reflect.ClassTag

def convert[T : ClassTag](key: String): Option[T] = {
  val ct = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
  someJavaMethod(key) match {
    case ct(x) => Some(x)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

It can be used as an extractor to test and cast to the proper type at the same time.

Example:

```
scala> def someJavaMethod(s: String): AnyRef = "e"
someJavaMethod: (s: String)AnyRef

[...]

scala> convert[Int]("key")
res4: Option[Int] = None

scala> convert[String]("key")
res5: Option[String] = Some(e)
```

**Edit**: Note however that a `ClassTag` does *not* automatically unbox boxed primitives. So, for example, `convert[Int]("a")` would never work, because the java method returns `AnyRef`, it would have to be `convert[java.lang.Integer]("a")`, and so on for other primitive types.

Miles's answer with `Typeable` seems to take care of those edge cases automatically.

Answer (score 18):

You could try [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s `Typeable`,

```
scala> import shapeless._ ; import syntax.typeable._
import shapeless._
import syntax.typeable._

scala> def someJavaMethod(key: String): AnyRef =
     |   key match {
     |     case "keyToSomeInt" => 23.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
     |     case "keyToSomeString" => "foo"
     |   }
someJavaMethod: (key: String)AnyRef

scala> def convert[T: Typeable](key: String): Option[T] =
     |   someJavaMethod(key).cast[T]
convert: [T](key: String)(implicit evidence$1: shapeless.Typeable[T])Option[T]

scala> convert[Int]("keyToSomeInt")
res0: Option[Int] = Some(23)

scala> convert[String]("keyToSomeString")
res1: Option[String] = Some(foo)

scala> convert[String]("keyToSomeInt")
res2: Option[String] = None

scala> convert[Int]("keyToSomeString")
res3: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I'd made my own `safeCast[T: ClassTag]` on an implicit conversion from Option[Any] but noticed primitives were always returning None. Using Typeable I changed the body to a simple `opt.flatMap(_.cast[T])` and it works great.